# Add UIView to reused UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am desperately trying to achieve the following effect: I have got a tableview where I would like to expand the cells on selection and show some additional information on it. I reuse table cells, just FYI. In the past I was able to achieve such an effect in another application, but this just does not seem to work for me at all. All the methods that are vital for this to happen are called and the row expands beautifully, but the `additionalInfo` table in the `showExpandedContents` method just will not appear!

- If I **create** the `additionalInfo` table in the initialisation of the cell, the table will appear but when I **then** try to load the data (and by that, also the cells) it just won't reload the table. 
  But the method that is responsible for this (`showExpandedContents`) table is definitely called.
- If I initialise **AND** set up the table in the initialisation code of the cell everything works fine.

So here is some code for you:

Here is the cell setup:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *cellID = @"MyCustomCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[MyCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }

    ((MyCustomCell*)cell).data = [arrayToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}
```

Here is the selection method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    //setting the current cell as the expandedRow, so that I can collapse it later
    expandedRow = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [((MyCustomCell*)expandedRow) showExpandedContents];
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [self changeRowHeightAtIndex:indexPath.row height:330];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [tableView endUpdates];



}
```

Here is the `-showExpandedContents` method in `MyCustomCell` where I would like to display the additional information:

```
-(void)showExpandedContents{

    additionalInfo = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, self.frame.size.width, 250)];
    [additionalInfo loadContent];
    additionalInfo.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xf9f9f9, 1.0);
    additionalInfo.layer.zPosition = MAXFLOAT;
    [self.contentView addSubview:additionalInfo];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

is giving you a fresh cell, different than the one that had `showExpandedContents` called.

Removing this line should fix the problem.

Comment: Oh Lord! This blindly copied line from the internet caused so much desperation! Thank you so much!

Comment: Cool! Now I'm curious how you are going to do that nice animation without reloading the cell. Please share when you have it.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean. I solved the problem by simply removing the line. Upon selecting the cell, it expands and shows additional info.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were using that line to get the table cell animation. I see now.

Comment: Nope, I just change the given row's height and the call to `-beginUpdate` animates it.